# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class Button

Tags: android

Error inflating class Button

Here is the code:

activity_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
        android:background="@drawable/border_white"
        android:text="Donor"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/donor"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
        android:background="@drawable/border_white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Recipient"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/recipient"

        />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.ankit.bloodbank;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mDonor,mRecipient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDonor =(Button)findViewById(R.id.donor);
        mRecipient = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recipient);
        mDonor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mRecipient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RecipientActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Please help to fix it. There is showing error in setContentView of MainActivity.
And this error is showing in each activity of the project. I just tried to launch another activity first and it shows the exact same error i.e., error in setContentView.

Comment: a hint: remove all the attributes except `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` and try to add them one by one to check where you got your error

Comment: and where is your `@drawable/border_white` ?

Comment: @AnkitKataria See my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `border_white.xml` in your `res/drawable` folder and check if at the end has something like:  `(v24)`.  
If this is the case then copy this file and paste it inside `res/drawable` not `res/drawable-v24`

Answer (score 0):

the `<selector>` node in `drawable/border_white.xml` lacks the required attributes `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width`, which renders it invalid. add the missing attributes and it should inflate. they most likely should both be `match_parent` (or `wrap_content`).

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are using LinearLayout into RelativeLayout and you are using orientation: vertical in RelativeLayout. You must use SP for text measurements, and you are using DP. Also you must use @String into res folder and @Color and @dimen.
The xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" library is never used.
Are you sure your font has bold style? why you want use android:state_pressed="true"?, when you press button automatically start new activity.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:context=".MainActivity"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                    android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
                    android:text="@string/donor"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/donor"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                    android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/button_margin"
                    android:text="@string/recipient"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_semibold"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:id="@+id/recipient"

                    />

        </LinearLayout>
```